# How to query distance-optimized route from MapBox Directions API?

Tags: routes, mapbox

I am able to query **duration**-optimized route from MapBox (see below), but how can I query **distance**-optimized? Maybe there is some attribute I should add?

https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving-traffic/23.13367%2C60.384991%3B24.823957%2C60.634221.json?geometries=polyline&alternatives=true&steps=true&overview=full&access_token=[mykey]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#directions) it depends on the used routing profile if the fastest or shortest route is calculated and on what type of way (e.g. highway, sidewalk):

> This API supports **four different routing profiles**:
>
> **mapbox/driving-traffic** for automotive routing. This profile factors in
>   current and historic traffic conditions to avoid slowdowns. Traffic is
>   available in these supported geographies.
>
> **mapbox/driving** for automotive routing. This profile shows the fastest
>   routes by preferring high-speed roads, like highways.
>
> **mapbox/walking** for pedestrian and hiking routing. This profile shows
>   the shortest path by using sidewalks and trails.
>
> **mapbox/cycling** for bicycle routing. This profile shows routes that are
>   short and safer for cyclists by avoiding highways and preferring
>   streets with bike lanes.

The Mapbox Directions API is powered by the OSRM routing engine. Some background information regarding profiles:

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Profiles

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/profiles.md

Comment: Thanks for answer, however it is still not clear to me. If I want to do routing for car I can use "driving-traffic" or "driving" profile. Both seem to optimize duration, not distance. I want to get the shortest route.

Comment: You could only use what is offered by the Mapbox Directions API. There is no profile for car routing which delivers the shortest route, only the four profiles listed in the docs.
If this doesn't fit your needs you may consider setting up your own routing engine with a profile which fits your needs: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend#quick-start or look for an alternative API.